# Are there any examples of how to go about using GoogleIdTokenVerifier in android?

Tags: android, oauth, google-signin

I am using Google Sign in in my android app. After the user is authenticated, I need to verify the `idToken`. I looked at the [google-page](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/idtoken-auth) on how to go about doing it.

```
private static GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier =
    new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
        .setAudience(Arrays.asList(String.format("android://%s@%s", SHA512_HASH, PACKAGE_NAME)))
        .build();
```

Not sure what should be the value of `transport` and `jsonFactory` here. How do I build a transport and jsonFactory? Are there any examples of this around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer [here](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/blob/af69ec272192484b7d7e516a42ddac9137c280b3/drive/deprecation/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/driveapimigration/MainActivity.java#L129).

for transport you can use `AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport()` and for jsonFactory `GsonFactory()`. You will need the following in your `build.gradle`.

```
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.26.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.26.0'
```